# Parsing a ZonedDateTime in jsp- which tag is to be used?

Tags: jsp, jstl, taglib

Trying to parse a date which is of type ZonedDateTime in jsp. created a custom tag for the same:

This the value which is being passed for date from the model to the view (jsp)

"2018-07-13T15:57:33.515+02:00[Europe/Oslo]"

In custom jsp tag, i have this:

`<fmt:parseDate value="${value}" pattern="yyyy.MM.dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSz" var="parsedDate" type="date"/>`
I am getting an exception :

`javax.servlet.jsp.JspException: In &lt, parseDate&gt
value attribute can not be parsed: "2018-07-13T15:57:33.515+02:00[Europe/Oslo]"`

Any idea whats wrong ?

Comment: Where and to what have you set `${value}`? You may want to add that to your question.

Comment: `<%@ attribute name="value" required="true" type="java.time.ZonedDateTime" %>

<%@ attribute name="pattern" required="false" type="java.lang.String" %>`

Comment: Do you want to exclude zone from date?

Comment: i do not have control over value obtained, but when i parse i would like to exclude it

Comment: yyyy-MM-dd''T''HH:mm:ss.SSSX try this format.

Comment: I see you're setting `value` inside of scriptlets, though it doesn't explain where the value is derived from and then you want to format using jstl. You need to use either scriptlets or jstl but not both (ideally the latter).

Comment: ah. my bad. i deleted all the custom tags and just used this:  https://github.com/sargue/java-time-jsptagsworks like a charm, thanks for the response !

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/sargue/java-time-jsptags - joda tags has been ported. this works .